# MYSQL select where column value matches another value in same column

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a database table that contains values where the meta_id corresponds to the data in the meta_data column. But now i want to display that data inside a bootstrap table.

I have a table like so in php myadmin

[image]

I would like the result to look like this:

[image]

I currently have this query written up but im confused about how to best do this.

I thought by counting the rows that exist and then dividing them by the table header count i should get table row loop that i can then insert my table columns into but its still creates more columns than i need.

```
<?php     


$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid=".$this->item->id." ORDER BY meta_data ASC";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->query();

$count=$db->getNumRows();

$meta= $db->loadObjectlist(); 

foreach($meta as $data){ 
$metadata .=  '<td>'.$data->meta_data.'</td>'; 
} 

$count = $count/2; // i know there will be only two th's

?>

<table class="table table-striped">

<thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>

<tbody>

<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) { ?>

<tr><?php echo $metadata; ?></tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Which is doing this:

[image]

Im getting close!

```
<?php 

$sql="

SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid=".$this->item->id." 

AND 

meta_id IN (SELECT meta_id FROM table GROUP BY meta_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

";

$db->setQuery($sql);
$meta= $db->loadObjectlist(); 
foreach($meta as $data){ 
$metadata .=  '<tr><td>'.$data->meta_data.'</td></tr>'; 
} 

?>

<table class="table table-striped">

<thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>

<tbody>

<?php echo $metadata; ?>

</tbody>

</table>
```

The above is now giving me this:

[image]

Comment: You have to check if the meta id is same then it will take the meta_data in same row.

Comment: @Lakhan thank you and yes you are totally right. But how? Im very close i think. I found another question on here and tried the mysql query and its getting closer. I just need to work out how to format the table rows now. Because i think the query is working.

Comment: please try it similar like that. $new_array=array();foreach($old as $data) { foreach($old as $data1) { if($data == $data1) { $new_array[][] = $data } }  } 
Use this type of concept to filter your array. After that you will execute your final new_array as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT "put here column name you want to display in html table " 
FROM table WHERE pid=".$this->item->id." ORDER BY meta_data ASC";
```

for example :  if you column name(s) are Item & price than query look like

```
$sql="SELECT Item,price  FROM table WHERE pid=".$this->item->id."
ORDER BY meta_data ASC";
```

so you get only item & price from database.

another approach is you can make some changes in your loop like,

```
foreach($meta as $data){ 
$metadata .=  '<td>'.$data->meta_data['Item'].'</td>
<td>'.$data->meta_data['Item'].'<td>'; 
}
```

Comment: Oh.. i dont have item and price in my table

Comment: Phpmyadmin only contains columns with the data. As per my screengrab at the top

Comment: just print  you object by  print_r($meta) after $meta= $db->loadObjectlist(); let me know what it return

Comment: I have added it to my  question

Comment: Im sorry but my question may be confusing. The database table is at the top. The other two image screen grabs are boot strap table son my page. I want to display the data from phpmyadmin to look like the bootsratp screen grab tables

Comment: You have to check if the meta id is same then it will take the meta_data in same row.